Triggering action upon entering conversdation state with Telegram Python Bot Library
I want my bot to send out a message when entering a new state in the conversation handler.
enter stage 1 -> "You entered Stage 1" enter stage 2 -> "You entered Stage 2" end of conversation triggered -> "Ending bot"
But I cant seem to find a way the library does this cleanly, hence resorting to sending the message from the function which calls the new stage.
start_handler -> "You entered Stage 1" -> Trigger state 1 stage1_handler -> "You entered Stage 2" -> Trigger state 2 stage2_handler -> "Ending Bot" -> Ends conversation
if name == 'main':app = Application.builder().token(API_KEY).build()

# Handler Creations
# COMAND HANDLERS
start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start_command)

# REGISTRATION HANDLERS
stage1_handler = MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, stage1_hander)
stage2_handler = MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, stage2_hander)

# Main Game Convo
conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[start_handler],
    states={
        STAGE_1: [stage1_handler],
        STAGE_2: [stage2_handler]
            }
)

app.add_handler(conv_handler)

# Polls the bot
print('Polling...')
app.run_polling(poll_interval=3)

async def start_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE): 
    print(f" Start command triggered")

    await update.message.reply_text(
        text = "You entered Stage 1",
    )

    return STAGE_1

async def stage1_handler(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    print(f" Stage 1 triggered")

    await update.message.reply_text(
        text = "You entered Stage 2",
    )

    return STAGE_2

async def stage2_handler(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    print(f" Stage 2 triggered")

    await update.message.reply_text(
        text = "Exiting Bot",
    )

    return -1

Is there a way for a function to be triggered upon my telegram bot entering a state?

this is currently not implemented in PTB. It's on the long and long-standing list of improvements for ConversationHandler, see https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/2770 and https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/2390.

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of python-telegram-bot.
